# Why locate gives more lines output than find

Tags: find, locate

For example I will look for everything which contains 'bin' in its name

`locate 'bin'`  gives me **7732** lines of output

`sudo find / -name '*bin*'` gives me **2730** lines of output

why?

Comment: How many lines does `locate -b bin` print for you? How many lines does `sudo find / -path '*bin*'` print? Does your `updatedb` use a config file like `/etc/updatedb.conf`? What is in the file? Please [edit] the question and add information.

Comment: Finding just one line that is in both files, and another line that is only in the larger file, would probably give a serious hint as to what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`locate` by default matches entire path so it prints every file in `/bin` for example. `find / -name` matches only base name of the file (without path) so for `/bin` it will print only files with bin in their name. So to make these results closer either use `locate --basename` or `find / -path`.

Comment: now when I do `sudo locate -b 'bin'` I get **2317** lines while with find I still have **2731**, there is still something left, I've noticed that locate doesn't look in /sys    do you know why?

Comment: `locate`  also uses indexed database. `updatedb` is typically distributed with a standard `updatedb.conf` which excludes directories like `/tmp`, virtual file systems, ISO mounts, usbfs etc. `find` searches *all*. Directories like `/sys` and `/proc` are virtual file systems (VFS)

Comment: thnak you, now I understand